# Akka Stream: Combine `Flow[T, T2, M] + Sink[T2, M2]` to get `Sink[T, M2]`

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

Given simple source/sink/flows:

```
val source: Source[Int, NotUsed] = Source(1 to 5)
val sink: Sink[Any, Future[Done]] = Sink.foreach(println)

val intDoublerFlow: Flow[Int, Int, NotUsed] = Flow.fromFunction[Int, Int](i => i * 2)
```

I can combine a `Source[T, M]` with `Flow[T, T2, M2]` and get a `Source[T2, M2]` with the `via` method:

```
val sourceWithFlow: Source[Int, NotUsed] = source.via(intDoublerFlow)
```

How can I do the analogous operation and combine a `Flow[T, T2, M]` with `Sink[T2, M2]` to get `Sink[T, M2]`

```
val sinkWithFlow: Sink[Int, Future[Done]] = ???
```

Comment: In this case a `Sink[Any, Future[Done]` is also a `Sink[Int, Future[Done]` already, since `Sink` is contravariant over its first type parameter.

Comment: That's true regarding type signature, but to get the flow function applied to the sink, I needed to use `flow.to(sink)` or `flow.toMat(sink)(Keep.right)`

Answer (score 1):

You're looking to compose your flow and your sink by keeping the materialized value of the latter. As by default the fluent DSL would keep the materialized value of the former, a simple `intDoubleFlow.to(sink)` would not work. You need to be explicit by using `toMat` and enforce a `Keep.Right`.

The resulting code is:

```
val sinkWithFlow: Sink[Int, Future[Done]] = intDoublerFlow.toMat(sink)(Keep.right)
```

More info on composing graph stages with regards to materialized values can be found [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.17/scala/stream/stream-composition.html#Materialized_values).